# Is there a way to get better minified HTML in JSF?

Tags: performance, jsf, jsf-2.2, bundling-and-minification

Google Pagespeed very often complains that HTML is not minified enough. In my case, 13% reduction could be reached. It's not much but I'm curious to know.

I'm using JSF 2, PrimeFaces, OmniFaces and GlassFish. Compression in Glassfish is on. All my resources (CSS and Javascript) are minified and combined with CombinedResourceHandler of OmniFaces. So everything is optimized for web.

[Google recommends](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources) to use an HTML Minifier. But this is not possible with JSF.

Is there something else I'm not aware of to get better results?

Comment: Nice question +1. My guess is that you'd have to extends the jsf servlet and add some minifier before the response is done. Don't take my words for it, this is just a wild guess. I hope someone more experienced is gonna answer your question though, yeah you know who.

Comment: put another server in front or use service like cloudflare and do minify on the fly.

Comment: Actually we use Nginx in front of Glassfish and I just realized that PageSpeed provide a module for nginx. I will give it a try. (Have first to discuss this with my system admin). I'll report when I get some results. Anyway there is maybe some optimization potential here, how JSF generate HTML.

Comment: Did google say where the 13% could be achieved? By using their proprietary algorithm? Or using gzip (as they also often recommend)?

Comment: Google is just mentioning that 13% reduction after compression can be reached. All recommendations can be read in the link above. As I mentioned above, I'm already compressing over Glassfish - is mentioned in PageSpeed as a "passed rule".

Answer (score 0):

MyFaces Core provides a way to enable html white space compression since 2.1.10.

Comment: if you use gzip encoding (which you should), whitespace compression is not needed in the sense that when it occurs a lot, gzip will assign it a short code and the result is effectively the same

Comment: Please note gzip requires to buffer the response, which increase server memory usage. The compression here is done at compile time, so it is done only once. Gzip compression increase cpu usage too, because it is applied per request. Instead, my advice is use an apache server to cache a gzipped copy of the resources (js and css files) and let the dynamic content (html) without gzip compression (but with white space compression).

Comment: @BalusC That sounds interesting too. Could be a nice feature to have in Omnifaces?

Answer (score 0):

We are using frontend-maven-plugin in combination with gulp. This allows you to write typescript and less/sass and create minified (bundles, zipped, etc) resource files.

You can spiking on https://github.com/ButterFaces/ButterFaces

Comment: Oh interesting, never heard about ButterFaces bevor. Is it possible to combine it with primefaces and Omnifaces?

Comment: Yes it works with OmniFaces out-of-the-box. To use it in combination with PrimeFaces you will have to do a little thing https://butterfaces.gitbooks.io/butterfaces/content/primefaces_integration.html